# Efficient way to check what the mouse is hovering over for a custom UI toolkit

Tags: algorithm, user-interface, desktop-application

This question isn't related to any specific language, I'm just asking about different algorithms.

I'm trying to make a custom UI from scratch for a desktop app. It needs to support lots of UI elements without lagging, and most of those elements have hover states. This means there needs to be an efficient way to check what (if anything) is being hovered over every time the mouse moves. I have a few ideas but they're all flawed and I'm not really sure what to do.

The best thing I've come up with so far is storing the bounds of the current hovered element along with all its neighbouring elements. If the mouse leaves the bounds of the element, it would check which neighbouring element it's inside of now and set that to the hovered element (copying its bounds and storing its neighbour elements and so on). Some of the neighbours could just be rectangles of empty space neighboured by other empty spaces and elements. I'm just asking because I'm not sure if this is the best solution.

(Also, if anyone knows the codebases of things like Qt and GTK well, what algorithms do they use?)

Comment: This seems like premature optimization to me. Have you determined that there is a performance problem? You're working under the assumption that a linear search would be too inefficient, but I highly doubt that: How many elements do you expect to have in your GUI? Say, you have a thousand elements (a really cluttered GUI...). Doing simple AABB testing will still be done in the blink of an eye: Clock rates are measured in GHz (10⁹). Linearly searching through a thousand elements won't be an issue at all.

Comment: @Luatic It's not really meant for one project, so I wanted to make it ablle to carry as much as possible. Would linear search really work? I thought it would start to lag at like 80 buttons.

Comment: @Luatic If linear search would work for 1000 elements then there's definitely no need for optimization. I'll just use SIMD instructions for the comparisons and it should be more than enough. Thanks!

Comment: Do some benchmarks, but - assuming you do simply AABB tests - it definitely won't lag at 80 buttons, even if you use a "slow" language like Python (just for fun, I just benchmarked, and it came out at a couple *microseconds*). What I would assume to typically be the sources of GUI "jank" are (1) rendering (if done in software) - there are millions of pixels on a typical computer screen; (2) lack of proper multithreading (application does heavy work in same thread as GUI, GC etc. interrupt smooth repainting).

Comment: Again, you're doing premature optimization! SIMD instructions are cool, but there is no need for them (yet). First write the code in the intuitive, straightforward way, then prove a performance problem - or convince yourself that there is none - and only *then* start to optimize - by doing low-level optimization (SIMD), algorithmic optimization (spatial indices), etc.

Comment: @Luatic You're right, I'll leave it simple and organized for now and do the optimizations later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One difficulty might be having complex shapes for your elements. But you could just use a box to have a first check and then check if it is really above your element.

What i would do is create a box for each element, make a BSP with these boxes to avoid checking every single on of them. And for all matching boxes check the one element the cursor is really on. And of course only do that for elements that have a hover state.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that most spatial indexing is very overkill for a GUI.

Comment: Surely, i think i depends on what you are trying to achieve. I wouldn't mind going for this kind of solution for a personnal project to try it out and learn something or just have fun. But yeah in most cases that wouldn't be necessary.